# Jackson: how to wrap object with a key, which is one of the properties of serialized object?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I would like to achieve following JSON structure:

```
"laptops":[  
      {  
         "apple":{  
            "serial":"value",
            "manufacture_date":"some_date"
         },
         "lenovo":{  
            "serial":"value",
            "manufacture_date":"some_date"
         }
      }
   ]
```

Values for `"lenovo"` and `"apple"` keys will have exactly the same structure. There will be no additional properties for different types of laptops. Having that said, there is no need to implement type hierarchy. And one pojo should do it:

```
public final class Laptop {

  private String serial;

  @JsonProperty(name="manufacture_date")
  private String manufactureDate;

  private String make;

  public Laptop() {}

  public String getSerial(){
    return serial;
 }

  public setSerial(String serial){
    this.serial = serial;
  }

  public String getManufactureDate(){
    return manufactureDate;
  }

  public setManufactureDate(String manufactureDate){
    this.manufactureDate = manufactureDate;
  }

  public String getMake(){
    return make;
  }

  public setMake(String make){
    this.make = make;
  }

}
```

As you see in `Laptop` pojo I am introducing `make` property, but I do not want it to be serialized into key-value pair. Instead, I want `make` value to become itself as a wrapper for the `Laptop` object.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Map<String, Laptop>`, where the key is the make of each laptop. And annotate the `make` field with `@JsonIgnore` to avoid serializing it.